# python if statement with multiple critieria

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

My objective is simple.

From the dataframe below (df3):

if mr_no is equal to a defined number (I have a list for this below) then fire, if fire1 is equal to covered then fire, and if fire2 is equal to primary or secondary then fire, otherwise if none of these three criteria are met than they are not fire.

df3:

```
     mr_no        fire1    fire2
0   A5155       covered  primary
1   FS2328      covered  neither
3   133158  not_covered  primary
4   FS2328  not_covered  neither
5   A5128   not_covered  neither
6   A5128   not_covered  neither
7   133158      covered  primary
8   133158  not_covered  neither
9   A5128   not_covered  neither
10  A5129   not_covered  neither
```

I've tried the following to extract the code I need:

```
    mr = ["A5115","133158","FS2114","FS2110","FS2115","FS2111","FS2149","FS2150","FS2017","FS2018"]

def fire(row):
    if row['fire1'] == ('covered') + row['fire2'] == ('primary') | ('secondary') + row['mr_no'] == (mr):
        return 'fire'
    return 'not fire'

df3['fire_final'] = df3.apply (lambda row: fire(row),axis=1)
```

However, my results are none found but I know there should be something:

```
IN:  df3.groupby('fire_final').ssno.count()

OUT:  fire_final
not fire      214166
Name: ssno, dtype: int64
```

I'm thinking my error is with my list, but my knowledge of programming is still novice so I'm not sure how to do a conditional for a list.

As always, I greatly appreciate the help.

UPDATE:

Trying the code recommended by edChum produced results but as you can see row 120044 and 120045 shows fire1 was 'covered' and fire2 was primary, but they came up as not fire but they should show as fire.

```
df3['fire_final'] = np.where((df3['mr_no'].isin(mr)) & (df3['fire1'] == 'covered') & (df3['fire2'].isin(['primary','secondary'])), 'fire', 'not fire')


         mr_no        fire1      fire2   fire_final
120020  203670  not_covered    neither   not fire
120021  001500  not_covered    neither   not fire
120022  5273    not_covered    neither   not fire
120023  190365  not_covered    neither   not fire
120024  A5155   not_covered    neither   not fire
120025  236707  not_covered    neither   not fire
120026  A9088   not_covered    primary   not fire
120027  A9088   not_covered    primary   not fire
120028  FS1476  not_covered    primary   not fire
120029  A9092   not_covered    primary   not fire
120031  FS1476  not_covered    neither   not fire
120032  FS1476  not_covered    neither   not fire
120033  AFM002  not_covered    primary   not fire
120034  A9092   not_covered    primary   not fire
120035  FS1476  not_covered    primary   not fire
120036  FS1476  not_covered    primary   not fire
120037  007881  not_covered    neither   not fire
120038  007286  not_covered    neither   not fire
120039  A010    not_covered    neither   not fire
120041  N5012   not_covered    neither   not fire
120042  FS1478      covered    primary       fire
120043  FS1478      covered    primary       fire
120044  A2075       covered    primary   not fire
120045  136492      covered    primary   not fire
```

UPDATE:

The recommendation from EdChum worked when I used | instead of &

```
df3['fire_final'] = np.where((df3['mr_no'].isin(mr)) | (df3['fire1'] == 'covered') | (df3['fire2'].isin(['primary','secondary'])), 'fire', 'not fire')
```

producing the desired results:

```
            mr_no        fire1      fire2 fire_final
120062  FS0937  not_covered  secondary       fire
120063  FS0937  not_covered  secondary       fire
120064  FS0900  not_covered  secondary       fire
120066  FS2037      covered    primary       fire
120067  A9090   not_covered    neither   not fire
120068  129440      covered    neither       fire
120069  FS1629      covered    primary       fire
120070  FS2037      covered    primary       fire
120071  FS2037      covered    primary       fire
120072  A9074   not_covered    neither   not fire
120073  ABE102  not_covered    neither   not fire
120074  ABE100  not_covered    neither   not fire
120075  A5125   not_covered    neither   not fire
120076  199424  not_covered    neither   not fire
120077  179873  not_covered    neither   not fire
120078  A021    not_covered    neither   not fire
120079  A022    not_covered    neither   not fire
120080  A022    not_covered    neither   not fire
120081  A022    not_covered    neither   not fire
```

Comment: I think you might need `and` and `or` instead of `+` and `|`. Those don't do what you seem to think they do.

Comment: I did something similar in the past and worked like a charm:  def label_race (row):
            if row['eri_hispanic'] == 1 :
                return 'Hispanic'
            if row['eri_afr_amer'] + row['eri_asian'] + row['eri_hawaiian'] + row['eri_nat_amer'] + row['eri_white'] > 1 :
            return 'Two Or More'

Comment: Difference now is that I have multiple criteria in the condition.  I tried .isin instead of == but that gave me an error.

Comment: but 'A2075' and 136492 are not in `mr` so why should that row be flagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this in a one-liner using `np.where`:

```
In [6]:
mr = ["A5115","133158","FS2114","FS2110","FS2115","FS2111","FS2149","FS2150","FS2017","FS2018"]
df['fire_final'] = np.where((df['mr_no'].isin(mr)) & (df['fire1'] == 'covered') & (df['fire2'].isin(['primary','secondary'])), 'fire', 'not fire')
df

Out[6]:
     mr_no        fire1    fire2 fire_final
0    A5155      covered  primary   not fire
1   FS2328      covered  neither   not fire
3   133158  not_covered  primary   not fire
4   FS2328  not_covered  neither   not fire
5    A5128  not_covered  neither   not fire
6    A5128  not_covered  neither   not fire
7   133158      covered  primary       fire
8   133158  not_covered  neither   not fire
9    A5128  not_covered  neither   not fire
10   A5129  not_covered  neither   not fire
```

it was unclear what you really wanted but it you want to return true if any condition is true then you need to or the conditions:

```
df['fire_final'] = np.where((df['mr_no'].isin(mr)) | (df['fire1'] == 'covered') | (df['fire2'].isin(['primary','secondary'])), 'fire', 'not fire')
```

Somethings to note, for arrays you need to use the bitwise operators `&`,`|`,`~` for `and`, `or` and `not` respectively this is because here we are comparing an array with some boolean condition and we want an array of booleans returned. For multiple conditions you need to enclose the conditions in `()` due to operator precedence.

Comment: So you want to or all the conditions? In that case replace & with |

Comment: this worked:  df['fire_final'] = np.where((df['mr_no'].isin(mr)) | (df['fire1'] == 'covered') | (df['fire2'].isin(['primary','secondary'])), 'fire', 'not fire')   thanks EdChum!  Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Python is not C++ nor C. As a result, it uses some different structures.

In your case, when you want an `if` statement to fire when `thing1` is true *or* `thing2` is true, you use `or` not `|`.

In Python `|` does bitwise `or` operation.

So you want something like this:

```
if (something) or (something):
    return 'fired'
```

Comment: @LOLKAT, these `|`'s are somehow a mix of C's `||` and Python's `|`. That's why I mentioned both C and Python's usage of `|`.